# overcoming lodash's deccision to not support bower

Tags: lodash

Up till now I was using bower to install lodash and was happy with having a script tag

```
<script src="bower/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

load the library.

As stated in https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#v400 - 
In version 4.0.0 lodash stopped supporting bower.

From some reading I did it seems like I will need to use npm to install lodash and possibly loadash-cli or browserify and use some combination of them but I was not able to find a clear guide on how to do all that.

So how do I get loadash 4.0.0 to run in a browser? (maybe some tool that will place it in my bower folder as if it was installed via bower?!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to dropping bower, lodash no longer ships a minified version. If you can live with an unminified version, the simplest set up is:

```
npm init  // <-- creates package.json file for your project, similar to bower.json
npm install --save lodash // <-- creates "node_modules" folder
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<script src="node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you want minification, you'll need to use a minifier like uglify.  The simplest way to do that would be this, since you're already using npm:

```
npm install --save uglify-js
node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs node_modules/lodash/lodash.js --compress --mangle > lodash.min.js
```

This will create the `lodash.min.js` file in your local directory. If you wanted to put that in bower, just change the path of the output to `bower/lodash/lodash.min.js`.

If you want to go for the "build system" route like browserify, there are a huge number of opinions and methods to do that; and without details of your needs it's hard to recommend something. Here's one recipe using [gulp and browserify](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md).  If lodash is all you need this is probably overkill; but if the number and complexity of your scripts grows you might appreciate it.

Comment: thank you very much. I will try the combination of npm with unglify-js into my bower folder.